# Event confirmation receipt emails not sending

Tags: civievent

I have two versions of our site - a live one and a development one. The dev one is a copy of the live site, although in maintenance mode so that it's not publicly available.

If I do a test sign up for an event on the live site, I get the email confirmation (receipt). If I do the same on the dev site, no email receipt is received. I did a test of the mail settings on the dev site and I get that email.

Any idea what could be causing the emails not to be sent? Thanks!

This is not a scheduled reminder - it's the email receipt that goes out when someone signs up for an email. The one you configure under "Confirmation Email" on the "Online Registration" tab.

The differences between the live and dev sites: settings files changed to point to right databases, URL, Drupal put into maintenance mode, search engines can't access the site, CiviCRM upgraded from 4.7.22 to 4.7.30.

CMS: Drupal; CiviCRM: 4.7.30

[image: Send test email]

Comment: since it isn't 'civimail' per se that is sending out the confirmation can you a/ tweak your tags for this, b/ be clearer about what "I did a test of the mail settings" means. Do you get receipts from a Contribution page. Do you get an email if you use Activity = Send Email etc etc

Comment: It was the send test email settings. I included a screenshot of the page above. We don't actually use contributions on this site since it's a business site. So I don't have any contribution pages set up. I did an Activity and the email from there sent. I'll see about setting up a contribution page to test.

Comment: Nope, nothing from a contribution page, either.

Comment: Not that you haven't asked yourself this already but is it an EXACT duplicate of the live site? You didn't alter any settings - like in the civicrm settings file? Last thought (I'm newer to Drupal so this is a stab) does being in maintenance mode have anything to do with it? Is it perhaps writing emails to a log file instead since you're in maintenance mode?

Comment: The Title of this question is "Event registration emails" which confuses me and may need rethinking.

Comment: And in the question "If I do a test sign up for an event on the live site, I get the email confirmation" again this does not sound like CiviMail, it sounds like either System Template Messages or Scheduled Reminders.

Comment: Yes, event registration emails (receipts) aren't sending - if someone registers for an event, no email goes out. Not to the recipient, not to the person who is CC'd to receive them.

Comment: The system template message was identical on both sites. I even reset the dev site to the default email for the online receipts. Still nothing. It's not a scheduled reminder - it's the receipt that sends after you sign up for an event.The one that you control on the event's config page where you tell it whether to send a receipt or not.

Comment: It's an almost exact copy. The only difference between the two is that I edited the Drupal and CiviCRM files to point to the correct database and URL. And it's always in maintenance mode. I test emails on there all the time and they send fine. This is the first time we've had issues with them not sending. Maintenance mode just means that you can only see the site if you're logged in and have permission to see it. Everything else on the site works the same.

Comment: Actually, I take that back - the live site runs 4.7.22 and the dev site is running 4.7.30. I upgraded Civi after doing the duplication. I can't test it with an exact copy of 4.7.22 because for some reason the site keeps trying to use the wrong database user even though the settings files have that info right and I cleared the cache (I have up another issue about that). Upgrading fixed that issue.

Comment: Quite a big update - are you using default SysTplMsg for events?

Comment: Yes, it's the default. I reset the messages on the dev site so that it always has the latest features/code for me to work with.

Comment: We had a similar issue. We used PayPal processor and no error was reported. However, using dummy processor we got the below error:
Call to undefined function mb_strtoupper() in <b>/home/<website>/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/html2text/rcube_html2text.php

It turned out that the mbstring extension for PHP was not enabled on the server. After configuring the "php-mbstring" extension emails started to work.

Note that we were getting contribution receipts without "php-mbstring"

Hope this helps

Comment: It's the same server and the exact same settings across both sites. I finally just restored it and did a version by version update. Somewhere along the lines it appears there was a break in one of the versions.